# How can i implement slider with two knobs in gwt

Tags: gwt

I want to implement slider with two knobs in GWT? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind going with third-party library there is JQuery wrapper: [spiffyui](http://www.spiffyui.org) ([demo](http://www.spiffyui.org/?widgets)) and it has [Slider.java](http://code.google.com/p/spiffyui/source/browse/trunk/spiffyui/src/main/java/org/spiffyui/client/widgets/slider/Slider.java). Here is what it does:

```
/**
 * This widget wraps the JQuery UI Slider
 * and allows for single slider or double slider with range.
 * 
 * All options can be get or set using generic 
 * get/setIntOption, get/setStringOption, get/setBooleanOption
 * methods, but some convenience methods are provided for most popular such as
 * setValues and setMinimum and setMaximum.  See SliderOptions for full list of options.
 * @see SliderOption
 */
```

Or if you want it implement on your own here is step by step tutorial: [Creating a GWT Wrapper for the JQuery UI Slider](http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/gwt-slider/)

Comment: Thanks very much for this.. I wil start wid it... :):)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to code a bit of that yourself, but you can start with the one from the [gwt incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/SliderBar) .  Get the source and add another "knob" element to it.  That way you can insure the two "knobs" interact the way you want them.

Comment: Ya.. I had started with gwt incubator and the implementation of 2nd knob. Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing the following to get a JQueryUI slider into GWT
http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/gwt-slider/

I just downloaded a custom minimized version of JQueryUI to include the slider (only 68k) which was pretty sweet. Ended up UI Binding it and it worked like a charm;

I customized the above to implement an percentage slider (one handle, limited to 0-100) which could be re-used pretty easily. You can find my version here [How to implement a JQueryUI slider in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665322/how-to-implement-a-jqueryui-slider-in-gwt)