# How to implement a JQueryUI slider in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gwt

I recently needed to implement a slider in GWT to capture the percentage progress an user had made on a task. I was not happy with the slider from the GWT Incubator and was not too keen on using an external library like spiffy UI or SmartGWT. What alternatives could I use to implement an effective slider in GWT without doing too much donkey work ?

Comment: This is suppose to be a `Question`?

Comment: Better ? Sorry pretty new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair amount of searching I decided on going with a JQuery-Ui slider that would be implemented through a java wrapper class. The interaction between GWT and the JQuery slider would be through the GWT Java Script Native Interface. To keep the additions to the required library as small as possible I downloaded a custom Jquery-Ui package (just core+slider) which was pretty light weight. The result was satisfactory for our needs, fitted into our MVP design pattern and was UI Bound.

The slider wrapper was as follows :

```
package za.co.bsg.ems.client.framework.ui.slider;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONNumber;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONString;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * This widget wraps the JQuery UI Slider and allows for single slider .
 * 
 * All options can be get or set using generic get/setIntOption, get/setStringOption, get/setBooleanOption
 * methods, but some convenience methods are provided for most popular such as
 * setValues and setMinimum and setMaximum.  See SliderOptions for full list of options.
 * @see SliderOption
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("Convert2Diamond")
public class SingleSlider extends Widget {

    private JSONObject defaultOptions;
    private List<SliderListener> listeners = new ArrayList<SliderListener>();

    /**
     * Create the default slider with the specified ID.  The ID is required
     * because the slider needs a specific ID to connect to.
     * @param id - id of the element to create
     */
    public SingleSlider(String id) {
        this(id, null);        
    }

    /**
     * Create a slider with the specified ID.  The ID is required
     * because the slider needs a specific ID to connect to.
     * @param id - id of the element to create
     * @param options - JSONObject of any possible option, can be null for defaults
     */
    public SingleSlider(String id, JSONObject options) {
        super();
        Element divEle = DOM.createDiv();
        setElement(divEle);
        divEle.setId(id);

        defaultOptions = options;
        if (defaultOptions == null) {
            defaultOptions = getOptions(0, 100, 0);
        }        
    }

    /**
     * A convenient way to create an options JSONObject.  Use SliderOption for keys.
     * @param min - default minimum of the slider
     * @param max - default maximum of the slider
     * @param defaultValue - default point of anchor
     * @return a JSONObject of Slider options
     */
    public static JSONObject getOptions(int min, int max, int defaultValue) {
        JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
        options.put(SliderOption.MIN.toString(), new JSONNumber(min));
        options.put(SliderOption.MAX.toString(), new JSONNumber(max));
        options.put(SliderOption.VALUE.toString(), new JSONNumber(defaultValue));
        options.put(SliderOption.RANGE.toString(), new JSONString("min"));
        return options;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLoad() {
        createSliderJS(this, getElement().getId(), defaultOptions.getJavaScriptObject());
        super.onLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnload() {
        destroySliderJS(this, getElement().getId());
        super.onUnload();        
    }
    /**
     * Gets the minimum possible value for the slider
     * @return Returns the minimum.
     */
    public int getMinimum() {
        return getIntOptionJS(getElement().getId(), SliderOption.MIN.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Sets the minimum possible value for the slider
     * @param minimum The minimum to set.
     */
    public void setMinimum(int minimum) {
        setIntOptionJS(getElement().getId(), SliderOption.MIN.toString(), minimum);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the maximum possible value for the slider
     * @return Returns the maximum.
     */
    public int getMaximum() {
        return getIntOptionJS(getElement().getId(), SliderOption.MAX.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Sets the maximum possible value for the slider
     * @param maximum The maximum to set.
     */
    public void setMaximum(int maximum) {
        setIntOptionJS(getElement().getId(), SliderOption.MAX.toString(), maximum);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for only 1 anchor
     * @param value to set.
     */
    public void setValue(int value) {
        setValueJS(getElement().getId(), value);
    }


    /**
     * Set an option numeric value
     * @param option the SliderOption
     * @param value the numeric
     */
    public void setIntOption(SliderOption option, int value) {
        setIntOptionJS(getElement().getId(), option.toString(), value);
    }

    /**
     * Get an option numeric value
     * @param option the SliderOption
     * @return value the numeric
     */
    public int getIntOption(SliderOption option) {
        return getIntOptionJS(getElement().getId(), option.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Set an option boolean value
     * @param option the SliderOption
     * @param value the boolean
     */
    public void setBooleanOption(SliderOption option, boolean value) {
        setBooleanOptionJS(getElement().getId(), option.toString(), value);
    }

    /**
     * Get an option boolean value
     * @param option the SliderOption
     * @return value the boolean
     */
    public boolean getBooleanOption(SliderOption option) {
        return getBooleanOptionJS(getElement().getId(), option.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Set an option string value
     * @param option the SliderOption
     * @param value the String
     */
    public void setStringOption(SliderOption option, String value) {
        setStringOptionJS(getElement().getId(), option.toString(), value);
    }

    /**
     * Set an option string value
     * @param option the SliderOption
     * @return value the String
     */
    public String setStringOption(SliderOption option) {
        return getStringOptionJS(getElement().getId(), option.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Add a SliderListener
     * @param l - SliderListener
     */
    public void addListener(SliderListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the SliderListener
     * @param l - SliderListener
     */
    public void removeListener(SliderListener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }


    private void fireOnStartEvent(Event evt, int value) {
        SliderEvent e = new SliderEvent(evt, this, value);

        for (SliderListener l : listeners) {
            l.onStart(e);
        }
    }

    private boolean fireOnSlideEvent(Event evt, int value) {
        SliderEvent e = new SliderEvent(evt, this, value);

        for (SliderListener l : listeners) {
            l.onStart(e);
        }

        boolean ret = true;

        for (SliderListener l : listeners) {
            if (!l.onSlide(e)) {
                //if any of the listeners returns false, return false,
                //but let them all do their thing
                ret = false;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private void fireOnChangeEvent(Event evt, int value, boolean hasOriginalEvent) {
        SliderEvent e = new SliderEvent(evt, this, value, hasOriginalEvent);

        for (SliderListener l : listeners) {
            l.onChange(e);
        }
    }

    private void fireOnStopEvent(Event evt, int value) {
        SliderEvent e = new SliderEvent(evt, this, value);

        for (SliderListener l : listeners) {
            l.onStop(e);
        }
    }


    private native void setIntOptionJS(String id, String option, int value) /*-{
        $wnd.$("#" + id).slider("option", option, value);
    }-*/;


    private native int getIntOptionJS(String id, String option) /*-{
        return $wnd.$("#" + id).slider("option", option);
    }-*/;


    private native void setBooleanOptionJS(String id, String option, boolean value) /*-{
        $wnd.$("#" + id).slider("option", option, value);
    }-*/;


    private native boolean getBooleanOptionJS(String id, String option) /*-{
        return $wnd.$("#" + id).slider("option", option);
    }-*/;


    private native void setStringOptionJS(String id, String option, String value) /*-{
        $wnd.$("#" + id).slider("option", option, value);
    }-*/;


    private native String getStringOptionJS(String id, String option) /*-{
        return $wnd.$("#" + id).slider("option", option);
    }-*/;

    private native void setValueJS(String id, int value) /*-{
        $wnd.$("#" + id).slider("option", "value", value);
    }-*/;


    private native void createSliderJS(SingleSlider x, String id, JavaScriptObject options) /*-{
        options.start = function(event, ui) {
            x.@za.co.bsg.ems.client.framework.ui.slider.SingleSlider::fireOnStartEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Event;I)(event, ui.value);
        };
        options.slide = function(event, ui) {
            return x.@za.co.bsg.ems.client.framework.ui.slider.SingleSlider::fireOnSlideEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Event;I)(event, ui.value);
        };
        options.change = function(event, ui) {
            var has = event.originalEvent ? true : false;
            x.@za.co.bsg.ems.client.framework.ui.slider.SingleSlider::fireOnChangeEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Event;IZ)(event, ui.value, has);
        };
        options.stop = function(event, ui) {
            x.@za.co.bsg.ems.client.framework.ui.slider.SingleSlider::fireOnStopEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Event;I)(event, ui.value);
        };

        $wnd.$("#" + id).slider(options);
    }-*/;


    private native void destroySliderJS(SingleSlider x, String id) /*-{
        $wnd.$("#" + id).slider("destroy");
    }-*/;
}
```

This slider was then incorporated into the following widget to create a percentage slider

```
package za.co.bsg.ems.client.framework.ui.slider;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.HasValueChangeHandlers;
import com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.IntegerBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import za.co.bsg.ems.client.event.IntegerValueChangeEvent;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class PercentageSliderWidget extends Composite implements SliderListener, HasValueChangeHandlers<Integer> {

    interface PercentageSliderUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, PercentageSliderWidget> {}
    private static final PercentageSliderUiBinder UI_BINDER = GWT.create(PercentageSliderUiBinder.class);

    @UiField
    Label headingLabel;
    @UiField(provided = true)
    SingleSlider singleSlider;
    @UiField
    IntegerBox percentBox;
    @UiField
    Label percentageSignLabel;

    private Set<ValueChangeHandler<Integer>> valueChangeHandlers;

    public PercentageSliderWidget(long taskId, String heading, int existingProgress) {
        valueChangeHandlers = new HashSet<>();
        JSONObject options = SingleSlider.getOptions(0, 100, existingProgress);
        singleSlider = new SingleSlider("singleSlider" + taskId, options);
        singleSlider.setTitle(existingProgress + "%");
        initWidget(UI_BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
        singleSlider.addListener(this);
        percentBox.setValue(existingProgress);
        percentBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Integer> event) {
                updateValues(event.getValue(), true);
            }
        });
        headingLabel.setText(heading);
        percentageSignLabel.setText("%");
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        updateValues(value, false);
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(final ValueChangeHandler<Integer> handler) {
        valueChangeHandlers.add(handler);
        return new HandlerRegistration() {
            @Override
            public void removeHandler() {
                valueChangeHandlers.remove(handler);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSlide(SliderEvent e) {
        percentBox.setValue(e.getValue());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(SliderEvent e) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(SliderEvent e) {
        updateValues(e.getValue(), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(SliderEvent e) {
        // do nothing
    }

    private void updateValues(int progressValue, boolean fireEvents) {
        singleSlider.setTitle(progressValue + "%");
        singleSlider.setValue(progressValue);
        percentBox.setValue(progressValue);
        if (fireEvents) {
            for (ValueChangeHandler<Integer> valueChangeHandler : valueChangeHandlers) {
                valueChangeHandler.onValueChange(new IntegerValueChangeEvent(progressValue));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My starting resource was the following
http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/gwt-slider/

Comment: I've never been more thankful for being able to work in pure JavaScript... :P